# Integration of $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+3x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I faced the following indefinite integration problem:
$$\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+3x}}dx$$

This [result by WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20sqrt%28x%2Bsqrt%28x%5E2%2B3x%29%29) suggests that there is an elementary way to compute this integration. But I don't know how to start. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

we set $$t=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+3x}}$$ then by squaring, We get
$$t^2-x=\sqrt{x^2+3x}$$
by squaring again, We get
$$t^4-2t^2x=3x$$
thus
$$x=\frac{t^4}{3+2t^2}$$
and
$$dx=4\,{\frac {{t}^{3} \left( {t}^{2}+3 \right) }{ \left( 2\,{t}^{2}+3
 \right) ^{2}}}
dt$$
for the integration use that the integrand can written as
$${t}^{2}-{\frac {9}{4\,{t}^{2}+6}}+{\frac {27}{2\, \left( 2\,{t}
^{2}+3 \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: That's the easy part, isn't it? Now you have to integrate that expression! (Or rather, $t \times$ that expression.)

Comment: the easy part? aha if you think so

Comment: the first is easy we obtain $\frac{t^3}{12}$

Comment: the second one can be written in the form $$\frac{3}{8}\int\frac{dt}{\left(\sqrt\frac{2}{3}t\right)^2+1}$$

Comment: [WolframAlpha can find partial fractions (link)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+(4t%5E4(t%5E2%2B3))%2F((2t%5E2%2B3)%5E2)).

Answer (score 3):

See the other answer. To find $\int \frac{27}{2(2t^2+3)^2}\, dt$, you can avoid using non-real numbers (notice that $2t^2+3=at^2+bt+c$, where $b^2-4ac<0$, has no real roots and no non-trivial factorization over the real numbers. We can't use partial fractions with real numbers).

See [this link (link)](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integration-of-rational-functions-easy/#partial-fraction-approach) ([Wikipedia (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions#Integrands_of_the_form_xm_.2F_.28a_x2_.2B_b_x_.2B_c.29n) also has some formulas), which shows the integration formulas over the real numbers of $\int \frac{1}{(x^2+bx+c)^n}\, dx$, $\int \frac{x}{(x^2+bx+c)^n}\, dx$, and see the examples there, in particular the example $\int \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}\, dx$. It generalizes. Notice that

$$\left(\frac{1}{\left(x^2+bx+c\right)^n}\right)'=\frac{-(2x+b)n}{\left(x^2+bx+c\right)^{n+1}}$$

$$\left(\frac{x}{\left(x^2+bx+c\right)^n}\right)'=\frac{x^2+bx+c-nx(2x+b)}{\left(x^2+bx+c\right)^{n+1}}$$

Use integration by parts, partial fractions. $$\int \frac{1}{2t^2+3}\, dt$$

$$\int u\, dv=uv-\int v\, du$$

$$u=\frac{1}{2t^2+3}$$

$$du=\frac{-4t}{(2t^2+3)^2}\, dt$$

$$dv=dt, v=t$$

$$\int \frac{1}{2t^2+3}\, dt=\frac{t}{2t^2+3}-$$

$$-\int \frac{-4t^2}{(2t^2+3)^2}\, dt$$

Use partial fractions. You could use [WolframAlpha (link)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+%5Cfrac%7B-4x%5E2%7D%7B(2x%5E2%2B3)%5E2%7D) if you want, but it's not needed.

$$\frac{-4t^2}{(2t^2+3)^2}=\frac{6}{(2t^2+3)^2}-\frac{2}{2t^2+3}$$

Now find $\int \frac{1}{(2t^2+3)^2}\, dt$ in terms of $$\int\frac{1}{2t^2+3}\, dt=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\int\frac{d\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}t\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}t\right)^2+1}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}t\right)+C$$